# On $L^\infty$ norm of solutions to time dependent differential equations

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes

I am new to the theory of differential equations and weak solutions.

I am looking for references regarding the analysis of the $L^\infty$ norm of weak solutions to linear second order *time dependent* partial differential equations in $\mathbb{R}^d$. The references can be anything from a textbook (if available) to a paper, providing fundamental (must-know) results and tools for the analysis of $L^\infty$ norms.

Also, are there any modern results regarding $L^\infty$ norms of solutions to

- linear third order time dependent equations?
- some specific non-linear time dependent equations (first order, second order)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Textbook and literature are largely divided by "type" of equations, with very different techniques/ideas used in different areas. In terms of time dependent equations, are you looking at hyperbolic equations, dispersive equations, parabolic equations, or something else entirely? In the generality you mention the question is a bit vague and perhaps too broad. Can you narrow down a bit what you are looking for?

Comment: @WillieWong Thank you for the comment. I am looking for $L^\infty$ analysis of time dependent hyperbolic, elliptic and parabolic equations.

Comment: That... is not really narrowing things down at all! Anyhow: in this generality the keyword for elliptic and parabolic equations is probably "maximum principle". There are multiple textbooks devoted to just this (Pucci and Serrin, Protter and Weinberger). Hyperbolic PDEs generally don't have a good $L^\infty$ theory in higher dimensions, beyond that which is derivable from Sobolev embedding and energy estimates. In one spatial dimension however the theory is robust. See e.g. C. Dafermos _Hyperbolic Conservation Laws in Continuum Physics_. or Serre's _System of Conservation Laws_.